# How many unordered hands in poker contain at least one pair?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> **Question:** How many unordered hands in poker contain at least one pair?

I am thinking like this:

$$^{13}C_1 \cdot ^4C_2 \cdot ^{50}C_3 + ^{13}C_2 \cdot ^4C_2 \cdot ^4C_2 \cdot ^{48} C_1$$

Or I should calculate another way?

Comment: I get your first summand; but what does the second summand represent?

Comment: That's the situation of two pair

Comment: And what makes you think you had not included it in your first summand? How was it excluded in that first summand?

Comment: (Also: when you say “at least one pair”, do flushes count as having “at least one pair”, since they are ranked higher than one pair, or not?)

Comment: It should not include flushes

Comment: Nor, presumably, straights. So you want hands with one pair, two pairs, three-of-a-kind, full houses, or four-of-a-kind.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**  You seem to be trying to add the number of ways of selecting exactly one pair and of selecting exactly two pairs.  However, your calculation is incorrect.  As Arturo Magidin pointed out in the comments, you would have to add all the ways of selecting two or more cards of the same rank. Those hands include selecting exactly one pair, selecting two pairs, selecting three of a kind, selecting a full house, and selecting four of a kind.

Exactly one pair:  Choose one of the $13$ ranks for the pair.  Choose two of the four cards of that rank.  Choose three of the other twelve ranks for the three singletons.  Choose one of the four cards from each of those ranks.

> $$\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{12}{3}\binom{4}{1}^3$$

Exactly two pairs: Choose two of the $13$ ranks for the pairs.  Choose two of the four cards from each of those ranks.  Choose one of the remaining $11$ ranks for the singleton.  Choose one of the four cards of that rank.

> $$\binom{13}{2}\binom{4}{2}^2\binom{11}{1}\binom{4}{1}$$

Three of a kind:  Choose one of the $13$ ranks for the triple.  Choose three of the four cards of that rank.  Choose two of the remaining $12$ ranks for the singletons.  Choose one card from each of these ranks.

> $$\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{3}\binom{12}{2}\binom{4}{1}^2$$

Full house:  Choose one of the $13$ ranks for the triple.  Choose three of the four cards of that rank.  Choose one of the remaining $12$ ranks for the pair.  Choose two of the four cards of that rank.

> $$\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{3}\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{2}$$

Four of a kind:  Choose one of the $13$ ranks for the quadruple.  Choose all four cards of that rank.  Choose one of the remaining $12$ ranks for the singleton.  Choose one of the four cards of that rank.

> $$\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{4}\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{1}$$

Adding these mutually exclusive and exhaustive cases gives the total number of ways of drawing at least one pair.

**Method 2:**  Alternatively, you can subtract the number of ways of not selecting at least one pair from the $\binom{52}{5}$ ways of selecting a five-card hand.  The number of ways of not selecting at least one pair can be found by selecting five of the thirteen ranks and one of the four cards from each of those ranks.

> $$\binom{13}{5}\binom{4}{1}^5$$

Therefore, the number of ways of selecting at least one pair is

> $$\binom{52}{5} - \binom{13}{5}\binom{4}{1}^5$$

Comment: Wouldn’t you also need to figure out how many hands have a full house, and how many hands have 3-of-a-kind and 4-of-a-kind, if you are using the first approach?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to figure out how many poker hands have no pairs. Assuming a standard $52$ card deck, it's $4^5*{13\choose 5}$ because every card must have a different face value. Then just subtract this number from the total number of poker hands. $52\choose 5$

Comment: You are only picking the rank, but you aren’t picking the suit. How does your counting distinguish the hand with the spade ace, two, three, four, and five from the hand with the heart ace, two, three, four, and five? Also, the order of the ranks shouldn’t matter, so how do you distinguish choosing ace, two, three, four, and five from choosing five, four, three, two, and ace?

Comment: Sorry. My question is asking for at least one pair

Comment: The order in which the cards are selected does not matter.  Your numerator still takes the order of selection into account.

Comment: @Jam: Yes, and he’s suggesting that you count all hands that *do not* have at least one pair, and deduce the number you want by taking all possible hands and subtracting the ones that do not have at least one pair. That’s a valid way of approaching the problem; unfortunately, his count is incorrect for what he is trying to calculate.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks. I forgot to add the $4^5$ term so now the product should cover all the suits and ranks instead of just the ranks. The fact that order doesn't matter is reflected in my answer. You have $13$ face values to choose for the first card. But you can't form pairs so there's $12$ for the second and so on.

Comment: @Ryan: No, you are definitely counting order. You are considering the order in which you select the ranks. Imagine there were only six ranks to choose from: you are saying we should take $6\times 5\times 4\times 3\times 2$; but that is not the way to pick five ranks, that’s the way to pick five ranks when order matters (in fact, there would only be six ways to pick five ranks out of six possible ranks, one choice for each rank excluded). So you are messing up in more than just forgetting the suits.

Comment: Ah I get it now. So it's essentially just picking $5$ face values from $13$ where order doesn't matter. $13\choose 5$. Good now?

Comment: Yes; and the suits is $4^5$ because you can assign the suits by increasing rank order, so here the order of the suits *does* matter. (This of course assumes that “at least one pair” excludes flushes and straights, which are hands that are “higher” than one pair but which you are counting...)

Comment: I think 13  pick 5 is better for unordered. Thanks!

Comment: But how about if there only singles?

Answer (score 0):

I like to verbally walk myself through this. It's honestly the only thing I got out of my discrete math class.

Let's work with the two distinct pairs case first since it's tougher. For our *distinct* pairs, we need to pick 2 distinct card values from the 13 card values, so that gives us 13 choose 2 and both pairs each have 4 choose 2 options since we have four suits and need to pick 2 distinct suits. Our last card then must be one of 11 (and so 11 choose 1) and it has four suits it could take.

So this hand gives

$$ \underbrace{{13 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}}_{\text{2 pair}} \underbrace{{11 \choose 1}{4 \choose 1}}_{\text{last card}} = 123552.$$

---

Now for the exactly one pair case. In this case, we pick one card value and the other three must be distinct from it and from each other otherwise it becomes a two pair situation.

We can pick our pair to be one of 13 card values and then we have 4 choose 2 such combinations for that pair due to suits. For our last three cards, we have 12 choose 3 card values we can pick from (12 to be distinct from the first, and choose 3 to be distinct from each other) and four suits for them.

$$ \underbrace{{13 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2}}_{\text{pair}} \underbrace{{12 \choose 3}\left({4 \choose 1}\right)^3}_{\text{last three cards}} = 1,098,240.$$

Comment: As Arturo Magidin pointed out, every hand with at least two cards of one rank contains at least one pair.  Therefore, it is easier to subtract the number of hands with no pairs from the $\binom{52}{5}$ ways of choosing a five-card hand.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, but it's probably less intuitive for a novice.

Comment: You would also need to count at least full houses (which have a pair and a 3-of-a-kind), if not three-of-a-kind hands (which arguably contain a pair) and four-of-a-kind hands.